# How to configure OneToOne releationship between the primarykey and foreignkey?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables, one table has id primary key and another table key is foreign key. How to map the one to one relation between the these tables.Please advise.

Table-1

```
date_id(PK)
start_date
end_date
create_date
modify_date
```

Table-2

```
product_id(PK)
product_name
productversion
date_id(FK)
```

While configuring the OneToOne relationship mapping in Table-1 bean,

```
private int date_id;
private ParoducttFeature paroductfeature;
```

getter/setter

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="DATE_ID")
public int getDate_id() {
    return date_id;
}

 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "daterange", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public ProductFeature getParoductfeature() {
    return productfeature;
}


public void setProductFeature(ProductFeature productfeature) {
    this.productfeature= productfeature;
}
```

Another table-2 bean:

```
private DateRange daterange;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="date_id")
public DateRange getDaterange() {
    return daterange;
}

/**
 * @param daterange the daterange to set
 */
public void setDaterange(DateRange daterange) {
    this.daterange = daterange;
}
```

I'm getting an error can't insert null values. Please advise why is this inserting null values.

Error stack Trace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Date_id', table 'Test.dbo.ProductFeature'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2989)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3501)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:227)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:207)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java
```

Hibernate session code :

```
Session session = (Session) HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

dateRange.setStart_date(date1);
dateRange.setEnd_date("12/31/2099");
dateRange.setCreate_date(date1);
dateRange.setModify_date(date1);
session.save(dateRange);

productFeature.setproductname("stack");
productfeature.setproductversion("1.23");
session.save(productFeature);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.flush();
HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

Comment: Can't insert null values where? Please post the complete error and stacktrace. Also, have you tried using `nullable = false` ?

Comment: I have posted stack trace error , please help me..

Comment: The problem is not in the mapping. The problem is in the code creating and persisting the entities. Show us this code.

Comment: @JB Nizet Updated the code, please advise what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a not null constraint on the `ProductFeature.Date_id` column in the database. This column is mapped to the property `ProductFeature.daterange`. And when you insert a ProductFeature in your code, its `daterange` property is null. So you're effectively inserting null into a column which has been configure to reject null values. So you get this exception.

If you add

```
productFeature.setDaterange(dateRange);
```

before saving the productFeature, it should work fine.